# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, batch-processing

I am getting the following expection:

```
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 3; expected: 1; nested exception is
org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 3; expected: 1
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:314) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

This occurs when  I try to cascade delete an entity (Kennel) that has a one to many relationship to another entity (Dog).

**Deletion code (using CRUD repository delete method):**

```
kennelRepository.delete(kennelEntity);
```

**Kennel Entity (Parent):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KENNEL")
public class Kennel implements Serializable
{
  //other fields and getters/setters

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "kennel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Dog> dogList = new LinkedList<Dog>();
```

**Dog Entity (Child):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOG")
public class Dog implements Serializable
{

//other fields and getters/setters

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "KENNEL_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_NUMBER", referencedColumnName = "KENNEL_NUMBER")
    })
    private Kennel kennel;
```

What could be causing this? I am almost certain that the mappings are correct?

I also tried changing the fetch type from `LAZY` to `EAGER` but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.This can happen in case where the entity has already been deleted manually from the backend database and hibernate is trying to delete it again.

2.Just check if there is no other process which is deleting the records

Comment: There is no other process deleting them?